# UIImageView not responding to UIPanGestureRecognizer gesture

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I've got 2 views. The idea is to select image from second view and place it on first view.
The problem is I tried to add pan gesture, it's not responding or calling the method. Please help. Thanks

Code in my First view

```
- (void)newStampImage: (UIImage *)inImage
{
    stampImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:inImage];
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *stampPanGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveStamp:)];
    [stampPanGesture setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [stampPanGesture setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [stampImageView addGestureRecognizer:stampPanGesture];
    stampImageView.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:stampImageView];
}
```

Comment: Have you set the delegate?[stampPanGesture setDelegate:self];

Comment: @URLArenzo see this line in the code and check the **Target**: `[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveStamp:)];`

Comment: @samfisher sorry, was surfing on mobile device.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

please add

```
stampImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: great! it's working now. I noticed the image is blocking my button. How do i bring my button to front? Thanks.

Comment: Classic... UIImageView is the only UIView that by default userInteractionEnabled = NO...
@RockBaby - you should call [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.myButton];

Comment: you can bring button's layer upward by `[button bringSubviewToFront: stampImageView];`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have done setting for recognizing gesture,i mean set gesturerecognization
property to yes,then it  might work.

Thanks